# Java: How can I design this class for having optional generics ParameterType?

Tags: java, oop, generics

I have this class in my code

```
public abstract class MyAbstractEventListener<E extends IMyEvent> {
    public abstract void handleEvent(E e);
}
```

and I can make instances in this way (let's call it A):

```
new MyAbstractEventListener<IMyEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handleEvent(final IMyEvent e) {
        // Method implementation
    }
};
```

But for my purposes, it would be ideal being able also to do this as well when there's no required event info (let's call this B):

```
new MyAbstractEventListener() { // Or receiving some unused parameter
    @Override
    public void handleEvent() {
        // Method implementation
    }
};
```

without having the warning about the class being raw and reccomending to parameterize it.

To clarify, I want the class to allow either the A or B instantiation, having the personal choice of using the one I prefer each time. If there's some generics parameter, the method receiving the IMyEvent object and if not, the method without parameters.

An example of code using this class would be:

```
EventBus.getInstance().addEventListener("some.string", new 
    AbstractEventListener<IMyEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handleEvent(final IMyEvent e) {
            // Sometimes does use 'e', sometimes doesn't. That's the point
            MyConfirmationWindow.showConfirmationWindow(MyWindowType.WARNING, "kk", "lll");
        }
    });
```

Is there a way? Any link or resource will be appreciated.

Comment: B must have an "is-a" relationship to `MyAbstractEventListener<? extends IMyEvent>`, or it it cannot be part of that class hierarchy.

Comment: Can you give some details as how you plan to call the handleEvent method if you have a mixture or handlers that require or do not require event information?

Comment: For example let say that you have a class that is the event dispatcher or perhaps the source of the events... whenever an event takes place then it call all the listeners and for those that can handle the event's info class, say X, it will call handleEvent(X) but for those that cannot handle the info it only calls handleEvent()? Is that it. Is it possible that you would have listeners whose event class does not match that event info class? How can you figure that out? I think the dispatcher code is quite important in order to figure out what is the best design here.

Comment: It might not be terrible just to keep a separate listener list and classes for those listeners that require event info and those that don't do so.

Comment: @ValentinRuano I added an example using the class. I expect it to be useful

Comment: @madtyn, What I would like to see is the example of the code that actually dispense the events to the listeners... is this hidden in a library that you are using or it is your own code.... I think if you try to implement that code first you will realized the difficulties of having to deal with two different ```handleEvent``` signatures + possibly the fact that the event info type is actually unknown in run-time... I am assuming that ```IMyEvent``` is not the only event info class, otherwise there would be no need for generics here.

Comment: @ValentinRuano The code is not mine, but it's legacy code in our current project and I'm trying to improve it. Is already implemented and working. IMyEvent is an interface, so you're correct, there are many event info classes. I can't paste now snippets (I'm in hurry now), but I will try to make it soon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you could make an abstract subclass :

```
public abstract class BlindListener extends MyAbstractEventListener<IMyEvent> {

    public abstract void handleEvent();

    @Override
    public void handleEvent(IMyEvent iMyEvent) {
        handleEvent(); // delegate to abstract method that ignores the argument
    }
}
```

This is actually a class that uses generics, but clients won't ever have to deal with them :

```
new BlindListener() {
    @Override
    public void handleEvent() {

    }
}
```

Instances that do need a specific type can still use the `MyAbstractEventListener` directly

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you will be able to avoid having tow `handleEvent` methods the way you described here.

But here is another approach using [Null Object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern) design pattern and single `handleEvent` method:

```
    new MyAbstractEventListener<IMyEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handleEvent(final IMyEvent e) {
            // Method implementation
        }
    };

    new MyAbstractEventListener<NullIMyEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handleEvent(final NullIMyEvent e) {
            // Method implementation
        }
    };        
    public interface IMyEvent{}

    public class NullIMyEvent implements IMyEvent{}

    public static abstract class MyAbstractEventListener<E extends IMyEvent> {
        public abstract void handleEvent(E e);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> public abstract class MyAbstractEventListener<E extends IMyEvent> {
> ```
>
> But for my purposes, it would be ideal being able also to do this as well when there's no required event info (let's call this B):

The question is: what does the class `MyAbstractEventListener` do with the information that the parameter type `E` extends `IMyEvent`? Is there any method in that class working on type `IMyEvent`?

If not you could simple remove `extends IMyEvent` to achieve your goal.

Otherwise you need a different class since  `MyAbstractEventListener` relies on type `E`extending (or implementing) `IMyEvent`.